# Infinite processing without a loop in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I am doing this first exercise in MPI where I should initialize a variable `token` with value 0 and pass it around the other processes, where each should receive the token and add +1 to it and then pass it forward until it comes back to the thread `rank = 0`. However, I'm stuck at the console waiting for an input and consuming a lot of processing power seen in `htop`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[]){
    int rank, psize, token, dest, src;
    
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &args);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &psize);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    
    if(rank == 0){
        dest = rank + 1;
        src = psize -1;
        token = 0;
        MPI_Send(&token, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, dest, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&token, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, src, src, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("Received token: %d", token);
    } else {

        src = rank-1;
        
        if(rank == (psize-1))
            dest = 0;
        else
            dest = rank+1;

        MPI_Recv(&token, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, dest, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        token++;
        MPI_Send(&token, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, src, src, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Why in your `else` block are you trying to receive from `dest` (rank+1) and send to `src` (rank-1)? I assume that just hangs forever. I think you mixed these up in the `else` block.

Comment: You also have to send/receive 1 element (instead of 4)

Comment: Oh, that is embarassing, however, I could not find what you pointed out @GillesGouaillardet, where am I sending/receiving more than 1 element?

Comment: everywhere `sizeof(int)==4`

Comment: Oh, I see, now it worked as expected! Thank you guys for your help and patience. :)